# Python insert dataframe into Mysql table error unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: python, mysql, sql, dataframe

I have a dataframe in python that I would like to push the data into a mysql table. I need to be able to overwrite any pre-existing data already in the table. The column names match exactly between the dataframe and the mysql table however I am getting error "ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'name1' in 'field list'"   name1 is in both the dataframe and the mysql table. I am not sure where I am missing some '' so that the query is read correct in sql. Please can you help? I've tried the "normal" stuff of double checking my quotations and semi-colons, parenthesis already.

```py
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="pppp",
  user="wwww",
  passwd="mmmm",
  database="gggg"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

#insert data
cols = "`,`".join([str(i) for i in final_as_df.columns.tolist()])

#sql statement to be passed into sql
sql = "INSERT INTO `MYTABLE` (`" +cols + "`) VALUES (" + "%s,"*(len(final_as_df.columns)-1) + "%s)"

mycursor.execute(sql, tuple(final_as_df.columns))

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "record(s) inserted.")

mycursor.close()
mydb.close()
```

dataframe in python final_as_df

```
    name1   name2   name3
0   7777    6666    5555
1   9999    4444    3333
```

MySQL Table named MYTABLE (empty of data right now; so name1, name2, name3 are just empty columns)

```
name1    name2    name3
```

Comment: If you are using MySQL please don't tag SQL Server.

Comment: Have you already tried to print your query before insert to make sure the string values are being parsed correctly? It is only a MySQL error. It always helped me with these types of errors.